# Monitor RAM from serial port; Labview DLL with change in system language

Tags: dll, windows-7, serial-port, labview, regional-settings

I have an executable written in Visual Basic that reads data from a serial port through a DLL made in Labview. The data is then plotted on a chart in real time.

After reinstalling the software with a different installer package, the serial port appeared to hang on read or write. I pulled up Portmon and ran the software again; read worked just fine, and write was labeled successful too, but the chart showed no data, and hardware plugged into the serial port was not properly returning to its base location after timeout.

This issue was only happening on the computers with French system settings rather than English, so I changed one of the computers to English system settings in the Language area of the control panel, then reinstalled the software. It worked!
Does anyone know why this is? I'm trying to figure out if the culprit is the Format settings, the non-unicode program settings, or just the windows language and location.
Are labview drivers different between languages? Is the format setting changing how the data is plotted, causing a failure?
Any suggestions are welcome.
If you would like more information, I made a post in NI before I tested Portmon or the language settings [HERE](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Serial-Port-Read-hang-in-Labview-DLL-read-by-Visual-Basic/m-p/3168040/highlight/false#M914656)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing system language / regional settings also changes decimal separators and other things. I have installed software developed in C# in different machines, producing different results and simply not running due to that fact.

I do not know the reality of the software and hardware you are using, but this might help pointing in the right direction :)

Comment: It sounds highly likely that the DLL is either sending a value with a comma instead of a point as the decimal separator, or expecting one in the instrument's reply, when the system language is set to French. Try French but set a customised decimal separator?

Comment: I switched the language to English, after testing French again, and now it's not working anymore. I made sure that windows format settings were a decimal instead of a comma. I tried running the original Labview program locally on the computer, and received an error -- something about initializing the driver. I have little to no Labview experience, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, BlunT! I just wanted to add some extra information:

I tested different settings for the software using the old installer, but changing it's config file to pull the new executables. What I didn't realize was that the old installer installed to each user's AppData/Roaming files; I got the executable to run for my user, but it wasn't running for the others.
I reverted back to the new installer (which saves the executables to ProgramData), changed all language settings to French Canadian, and changed the decimal separator from "," to "."
It is now working for my user name, and should be working for others' now, as well.

Just another reason to make sure you install to ProgramData if the installed files aren't specified to each user!